# Are there any Ruby clients for Cassandra with counters and supercolumn?

Tags: ruby, cassandra, super-columns

Are there any Ruby clients for Cassandra with support of counters and supercolumns?

1) gem cassandra doesn't support counters

2) gem cassandra-cql doesn't support supercolumns (cql doesn't support them)

Comment: You can use the Java client with JRuby...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `'cassandra'` gem does support counters, its just not well documented. Support was added in May 2011 ([a1a085469](https://github.com/twitter/cassandra/commit/a1a0854692231b7047940aae28be381ca69869d1)). To increment a counter:

```
@twitter.add(:UserCounters, 'bob', 5, 'tweet_count')
```

Where

- `:UserCounters` is the column family
- `'bob'` is the row key
- `5` is the amount to increment the counter by
- `'tweet_count'` is the column_name

Comment: @brs - if you are happy with the answer feel free to mark it as Accepted, hint hint :)

Comment: I am trying to get this code working... have posted a question... can you please help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396542/unable-to-use-cassandra-counter-column-with-cassandra-gem