# Unable to use cassandra counter column with cassandra gem

Tags: ruby, cassandra, cql

I have created a column family by following command using cqlsh:

```
create table mystats (key PRIMARY KEY, count counter);
```

Now from the cqlsh I am able to increase the counter column but when I attempt to do this from cassandra gem, as adviced at:
[Are there any Ruby clients for Cassandra with counters and supercolumn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9307825/are-there-any-ruby-clients-for-cassandra-with-counters-and-supercolumn)

So when I use:

```
@stats.add(:mystats, 'randomkey', 1, 'count')
```

I get an error:

> Cassandra::AccessError at /client Invalid column family "mystats"

When I further looked into it, I found that the error is raised from the gem:
in file: https://github.com/twitter/cassandra/blob/master/lib/cassandra/columns.rb

```
def column_family_property(column_family, key)
      cfdef = schema.cf_defs.find {|cfdef| cfdef.name == column_family }
      unless cfdef
        raise AccessError, "Invalid column family \"#{column_family}\""
      end
      cfdef.send(key)
    end
```

Can anyone please point out what I might be doing wrong here..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That client has not yet been updated to support CQL3.  I'm not aware of a CQL3-aware Ruby client, so your best bet is probably to create a Thrift-compatible table (TLDR add `WITH COMPACT STORAGE` to your table definition).

Comment: adding with compact storage while creating the table fixed the issue. i found the solution last night in cassandra irc.. thanks answering the question though..

Comment: just launched https://github.com/hsgubert/cassandra_migrations to integrate rails with CQL3 and migrations to manage cassandra schema